# wxpython demo code error

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, wxpython

Please excuse me for asking such an amateur question, but I have just started using wxPython. When I tried to copy and paste the demo code for GridLabelRenderer.py into a new python file, I always get an error message:

```
IDlE Subprocess: no IP port passed in sys. argv.
```

I believe the message has something to do with how my file is no longer saved in the demos folder, and the error is talking about this bit of code, I believe also:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, os
    import run
    run.main(['', os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Is there something I must do whenever I copy and paste demo code into a new file at a new location so that it runs perfectly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running the code without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little about this on the wxPython wiki: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code

That might help you in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Code for wxPython demos is made to run inside the demo frame. In order to use the code the best method is to take the classes and instantiate them in your application Frame.

The simplest way for the GridLabelRenderer.py could be:

```
imports....
classes...

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    ...................

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
            self.p = TestPanel(self, None)

    MyFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Don't forget to copy images.py from the demo directory to your directory or to a directroy in your pythonpath in order for images.py to be imported by class MyCornerLabelRenderer